# Mongoose open connection issue with Supertest

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, supertest

I am unable to run multiple Supertest/Mocha tests as I get an error `Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.` - I found this [post](http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication/2/02) which suggest looping and checking connection status. Wondering if there is a better way? perhaps something that was added in Supertest recently to handle this.

Comment: You don't have to open a new connection for each test, connect once at the top level of your test and re-use the connection.

Answer (score 2):

In your Mocha tests add a `before` function to connect to MongoDB like so

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

describe('My test', function() {
    before(function(done) {
       if (mongoose.connection.db) return done();
       mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/puan_test', done);
    });
});
```

Comment: Another possibility is to check if [`mongoose.connection.readyState`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-readyState) equals 1

Comment: Bulkan's suggestion in combination of robertklep's worked out well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - was pretty close. What I had to do was remove the describe method call and place a before() call in a common file to all tests - supertest or just straight mocha unit tests.

```
var db;

// Once before all tests - Supertest will have a connection from the app already while others may not
before(function(done) {
  if (mongoose.connection.db) {
    db = mongoose.connection;
    return done();
  }
  db = mongoose.connect(config.db, done);
});

// and if I wanted to load fixtures before each test
beforeEach(function (done) {
  fixtures.load(data, db, function(err) {
    if (err) throw (err);
    done();
  })
});
```

By omitting the describe() call the above it makes it available to all tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Also you can use the 'open' event to call the 'done' callback
// inside the 'before' Mocha hook.

    before((done) => {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test_db');
        mongoose.connection
            .once('open', () => {
                done();
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
                console.warn('Problem connecting to mongo: ', error);
                done();
            });

    });
```